# needs suggestions for online eCommerce website

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, payment-processing

i developed my Dad Bookshop website in codeigniter. 
i have completed till adding books to the cart and displaying its total price 
i.e user have to sign up/sign in to continue for adding books to kart.

Now i am stuck in the payment work. My dad said that "customer should be able to pay online , and i have to save the customer-id into my `payment_received` table after the successful payment done by the customer.

So that we can send books to the customer after seeing the customer in the `payment_received` table.

So please help me. I am very confused in this stuffs. Please give me some suggestion to implement payment stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for pay-pal gate way. You will get more online help for integrating pay-pal with your website. Very secure payment-gateway and easy set up for developers.

Comment: have you implemented pay-pal with your any projects?

Comment: Yes, I did.. You will get hundreds of online reference for the same.. go ahead

Comment: okay i will give a try